# How can I get metadata and my image to show up on OpenSea Testnet?

Tags: solidity, nft, remix

I followed along with Remix's beginner NFT course and successfully deployed a few NFTs using the Goerli testnet and their provided IPFS data. I uploaded my own image and metadata and can see it on IPFS but neither the metadata nor the image is populating on OpenSea.

Here is the code for the contract I am deploying:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.0/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.4.0/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Donation is ERC721, Ownable {
constructor() ERC721("Donation", "DONO") {}

```
function _baseURI() internal pure override returns (string memory) {
    return "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXZKcU9WDZxvXvxoAL4YdZVR5Ssj97ayEYRPqYBHrRSb2";
}

function safeMint(address to, uint256 tokenId) public onlyOwner {
    _safeMint(to, tokenId);
}
```

}

Please see the URL that I return for my metadata and subsequent link to my image. Is there anything you see that is immediately wrong that would indicate why nothing is populating (in the JSON file, code, or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0):

For ERC721, the `_baseURI` will essentially be the base to be combined with the NFT's token id, so for example NFT with token ID 0 will have the `tokenURI` of:

```
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXZKcU9WDZxvXvxoAL4YdZVR5Ssj97ayEYRPqYBHrRSb2/0
```

which in this case after checking is invalid as `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXZKcU9WDZxvXvxoAL4YdZVR5Ssj97ayEYRPqYBHrRSb2` should be the valid `tokenURI` itself. OpenZeppelin designed the ERC721 contract this way as it is the most gas-efficient way to create a standard ERC721 NFT. However, the drawback is that it made it difficult to provide modified URI for each token ID.

If you like to set `tokenURI` with different base for different token ID, then you should instead check `ERC721URIStorage` in the [contract wizard](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/wizard). This way, the ERC721 NFT contract will have the `_setTokenURI(tokenId, uri)` function, which allows you to modify the `tokenURI` for different token ID. However, keep in mind that this will be very expensive on the user side as `string` inputs cost a lot in EVMs.

Hope this helps~

Comment: Great, thank you. How do I get https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmXZKcU9WDZxvXvxoAL4YdZVR5Ssj97ayEYRPqYBHrRSb2 to be the only tokenURI for my ERC721's instead of adding the token ID at the end?

Comment: Do you mean for all token IDs they all have this token URI?

Then you'll just need to overwrite the `tokenURI` function to return this string without any additional if statement or other logic